# NFC can't send data Android 4.0.3

Tags: java, android, nfc, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nexus-s

I have an NFC Device (***SCL3711***) and ***Google Nexus S*** phone. I have write an application which send data from the phone to NFC Device and vice versa. Everything works excellent on ***Android 2.3.3***. Now I update my Nexus S operating System to ***4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich*** and everything stops working. Now I can't send data from my phone to NFC Device and vice versa. As I can understand the main reason is that I cant connect to the device, but why I can't understand.

Please, help me, provide some links or information consider to this question. Everything can be helpful for me.

#### Phone Log

```
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): Discovered P2P Initiator
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 46 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 66 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 6d 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 10 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 02 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 02 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 00 
01-25 13:12:42.629: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 00 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 03 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 02 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 00 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 03 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 04 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 64 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 07 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:42.633: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 03 
01-25 13:12:42.688: DEBUG/NfcService(23320): LLCP Activation message
01-25 13:12:42.688: INFO/NFC JNI(23320): LLCP Link activated (LTO=100, MIU=128, OPTION=0x03, WKS=0x03)
01-25 13:12:42.688: INFO/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): LLCP activated
01-25 13:12:42.692: DEBUG/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): onP2pInRange()
01-25 13:12:42.704: DEBUG/AudioHardware(82): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
01-25 13:12:42.704: DEBUG/AudioHardware(82): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
01-25 13:12:42.793: DEBUG/dalvikvm(23320): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2291K, 27% free 12018K/16327K, paused 51ms
01-25 13:12:42.793: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(23320): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.179MB for 1463056-byte allocation
01-25 13:12:42.821: DEBUG/dalvikvm(23320): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 18% free 13447K/16327K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-25 13:12:43.708: INFO/NFC JNI(23320): LLCP Link deactivated
01-25 13:12:43.708: DEBUG/NfcService(23320): LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
01-25 13:12:43.708: INFO/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): LLCP deactivated.
01-25 13:12:43.708: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): Failed to accept incoming socket  0x0096[NFCSTATUS_ABORTED]
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): Discovered P2P Initiator
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 46 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 66 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 6d 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 10 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 02 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 02 
01-25 13:12:43.915: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 00 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 00 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 03 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 02 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 00 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 03 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 04 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 64 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 07 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 01 
01-25 13:12:43.918: DEBUG/NFC JNI(23320): 03 
01-25 13:12:43.985: DEBUG/NfcService(23320): LLCP Activation message
01-25 13:12:43.985: INFO/NFC JNI(23320): LLCP Link activated (LTO=100, MIU=128, OPTION=0x03, WKS=0x03)
01-25 13:12:43.985: INFO/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): LLCP activated
01-25 13:12:44.989: INFO/NFC JNI(23320): LLCP Link deactivated
01-25 13:12:44.989: DEBUG/NfcService(23320): LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
01-25 13:12:44.993: INFO/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): LLCP deactivated.
01-25 13:12:45.747: DEBUG/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): Debounce timeout
01-25 13:12:45.747: DEBUG/NfcP2pLinkManager(23320): onP2pOutOfRange()
01-25 13:12:47.141: DEBUG/AudioHardware(82): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
01-25 13:12:47.141: DEBUG/AudioHardware(82): closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
```

Comment: This is more a user issue than a programming one. I guess you flashed without performing full wipe or maybe there's a problem with the new ROM. Try asking on http://forum.xda-developers.com/ or http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you installed ICS rom by yourself? Maybe it's related to the famous ICS bug in Nexus S semi-official! update.

Comment: Could you please share us with more information?
I mean could you please explain briefly about how to change the protocol from ndef to snep?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I close this question as I found solution, the main reason was that protocols changes instead of ***ndef*** now we must use ***snep*** protocol. If you have same problem change protocol type.

Comment: How can I do that? Also, this protocol change has to be made only when you are exchanging nfc data between ICS device or also from ics-to-another and another-to-ics?